# get remote push notification message in background in iOS

Tags: ios, background, push-notification

I have an app which need to get the message of the remote push notification in background so that when the user tap the app icon and resume/launch the app, the app can show an alert view which displays the notification message. 
What I plan to do is to use the function

```
"application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:"
```

which will be called when the notification has arrived when the app is in background. I will first record the remote notification message in this function and then when the app is launched or resumed to foreground, I will show the alert view to display the saved message. 
Does anyone have the same experience?

Answer (score 0):

You can do as you said. It will work. 
But, keep in mind that if ever the app is not in background (was quit manually by the user) the function `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` will never be called. 
If everything is ok, you'll have to store the message in your data model. Also think of the case where multiple notifications are received before the user open the app.

Comment: Or indeed the case where the notification wasn't received; push is pretty reliable but not guaranteed. Best practice is to check with the server when the app is launched/resumes in case anything was misssed

Comment: Ok. So when the app is not running I will have no way to get the message?

Comment: Unfortunately not :/  Exept in the case where your app is not running, but is launched via the notification.

Comment: The solution would be to implement in your app a function that says to your server that the notification was received (in that case you were able to store the message local in the app). Then you can delete the pending message/notification on your server DB. If your server didn't receive the call back, it means that either the app is not launch or the device is turn off. In that case you'll have to implement another function which is call when your app is launch asking to your server all pending message ;)